# Dynamic dropdown based on the current year in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to create a dynamic drop down list based on the current year?   For example, I want to create a dropdown based on the current year (2019); which have 5 options:

- 2019
- 2020
- 2021
- 2022
- 2023

Then, starting 1/1/2020, the dropdown would automatically update to 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, and 2024. Is this possible to do with some expression in the data validation drop down?

Comment: Just make a table, with the first cell's formula `=YEAR(TODAY())`, and then plus one for the rest of the years.

Comment: @BigBen.....Thanks....Works like a charm.  I think I was trying to make it more difficult than it should be.  Thanks for your help.....Any ideas on the drop down for the days of the month based on the year and month selected?  Thanks again......

Comment: What format are the months in? Number (01) or text (Jan)?

Comment: @BigBen...….I have both.  The month drop down is text (January) but in the code, I get the month number (1) so I can find the last day of the month.  Then it fills some cells in a calendar on the sheet in the correct day of the week.  I'm looking to populate a drop down with the days as numbers because I'm building a sql string to query a database and bring back any data for that particular date....thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dynamic" validation in VBA could be achieved through rewriting the validation every time, when it is needed. In the worse case, it could be every time the worksheet is opened or even every time when a selection is changed, probably through events.

The validation in excel is could be list and in VBA this list is passed as a string separated with commas. Thus, the string `2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023` is quite a good example of the expected list. There are different ways to do it, probably with a loop would be the "fanciest one", but as far as the values are only 5, then writing them manually is probably suitable as well.

**TL DR** - run this in a `Workbook_Open()` event:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim validationString As String
    validationString = Year(Now()) & ", " _
                    & Year(Now()) + 1 & ", " _
                    & Year(Now()) + 2 & ", " _
                    & Year(Now()) + 3 & ", " _
                    & Year(Now()) + 4

    With Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                        Operator:=xlBetween, _
                        Formula1:=validationString
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place these formulas in two separate tables without headers & starting in row 1

Year:

```
=YEAR(TODAY())+ROW()-1
```

Month column 1:

```
=SWITCH([@Column2],1,"Jan",2,"Feb",3,"Mar",4,"Apr",5,"May",6,"Jun",7,"Jul",8,"Aug",9,"Sep",10,"Oct",11,"Nov",12,"Dec")
```

and column 2:

```
=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+ROW()-1,DAY(TODAY())))
```

..and you'll get dynamic references that start from current date